# How to get custom designer properties in user control to have value at run-time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls

I have created a composite user control containing a label, a checkbox, and a button. I have set certain properties to be set in the form designer.

```
public partial class ctlBoundCheckButton : UserControl
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    public string _chkText { get; set; }
    public string _btnText { get; set; }
    public string _lblText { get; set; }

    public ctlBoundCheckButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        checkBox1.Text = _chkText; // _chkText is null :(
        button1.Text = _btnText;
        label1.Text = _lblText;
    }
```

When I drop this user control onto a form, the custom properties show up fine in the form designer, and I can assign values to them:

[image]

But the properties are null at run time. As you can see in the control's constructor, the values remain null. What is the proper way to set up custom properties in composite custom controls?

Comment: Use the property Setter, not the Constructor, if you want to assign a Property value of your UC to the Property of a child Control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others suggested, you can try to set the properties in the get set method.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
public partial class ctlBoundCheckButton : UserControl
    {

        [Browsable(true)]
        public string _chkText
        {
            get { return checkBox1.Text; }
            set { checkBox1.Text=value; }
        }
        public string _btnText
        {
            get { return button1.Text; }
            set { button1.Text = value; }
        }
        public string _lblText
        {
            get { return label1.Text; }
            set { label1.Text = value; }
        }

        public ctlBoundCheckButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
          

        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]